# GCM notification doesn't show up in the notification bar. Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have tested my application on my phone and eclipse emulator(targeted at google api level 16), but the coming notification will only show up in the notification bar in the real phone  but not in emulator. Any ideas whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you can get a `regID` when you work on emulator?

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
  GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
  Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
}
```

Comment: is it same with real device regID ?

Comment: the same? it shouldn't be the same

Comment: Yes, it should be different and on your server site, you must save these regID.

Comment: I mean do you send push notification either emulator regId or device regID ?

Comment: i stored the regid to my server once the device get registered. and once a new msg is generated, it will be sent to all devices

Comment: So you stored 2 different regIds (one of them your emulator other real device). If it is, there should be no problem.

Comment: but why the emulator doesnt get the notification? is there some settings i should take care of?

Comment: Ok, i will check it on my project, give me 1-2 hours