# Not able to get notification in bar when app is opened

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have implemented push notification using gcm in my ionic 2 app, the notification works fine in background and foreground, but the issue is that when app is in foreground the notification doesn't appear in notification bar. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [forum:Ionic 2, Android notification received but banner not showing on device](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1850).

It stated that if the app is in the foreground, the notification is not shown in the system tray. That only happens when the notification is received while the app is in the background.

Additional references:

- [GCM notification doesn't show up in the notification bar. Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490762/gcm-notification-doesnt-show-up-in-the-notification-bar-android)
- [push notification doesn't show up on status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065875/push-notification-doesnt-show-up-on-status-bar)
- [Android - GCM push notifications not appearing in notifications list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482593/android-gcm-push-notifications-not-appearing-in-notifications-list)

Comment: that is not an answer, that guy has the same problem which i am facing, i need its solution